# Is it possible to force Chrome to refresh app notification settings when using Notification delegation

Tags: trusted-web-activity, twa

In a previous answer regarding Notification Delegation between Chrome and an Android TWA app it was said that:

> "If the TWA has notifications disabled in Android Settings, we disable
>   them in Chrome instead. There's a little bit of latency with how this
>   gets propagated, but things should get updated on the next TWA launch
>   at latest.

[How exactly Notification Delegation does work?](https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/svgomg-twa/issues/60)

On my site I am sending the user to androids app notification settings when I find that notifications are not allowed in the browser.
But upon the users immediate return, the changes are not propagated to Chrome (to be expected from the comment above since the TWA is not launched again).

I wonder if there is anyway I can speed this up? Otherwise the user is forced to exit the page completely and restart the app before the permission is granted, which is not a very good user experience.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the only workaround would be to force restarting the application, which is not a great user experience. I have filed an issue on Chromium bugs to track a fix for this: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1064300